# what is the best choice to replace RDS Server ...LTSP or XDMCP in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ltsp, xdmcp

At work I need to replace Remote desktop server with same ubuntu server that give me ability to attach hp thin clients with it so users can login to desktop and run application same as windows RD.

For 3 days I searched and found this 2 services LTSP & XDMCP but can't identify which one is more suited.

Comment: XDMCP does not do encrypting if that is an issue for you.

Comment: lack of encryption is not a problem for me inside my network, any ideas?